# Jupyter notebook autocomplete showing duplicate options

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Jupyter notebook's autocomplete seems working, but somehow it will show duplicate options for the method. For example below:
[image: np.allclose duplicate entry]
[image: jupyter duplicate entries]

For each possible options, drop down menu will show 2 identical choices. Why this happen and how to fix it?

Comment: This is a known issue due to completions coming from 2 completions sources. Fix is in progress.

Answer (score 5):

Relevant Github issue: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/10969

This should be fixed in Ipython 6.3 release (track milestone completion here: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/milestone/48)