# How can stop running two Python3 Versions on Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, version, jupyter

After reset my Mac, I installed Anaconda3 and add Python2 environment to Jupyter Notebook. Then I have this problem when I click the tap. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nt2vW.jpg)

Always two same functions appears. Therefore, I guess Jupyter Notebook is working on two Python3s. How can I solve this? Anybody had the same problem?

Environment: macOS High Sierra
Python3 3.6.4 installed from Anaconda. 
Python2 2.7.15 already installed from macOS (I guess).
Anaconda 4.4.10
Jupyter 5.4.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: SO is very picky about using links. It's best to post the error text directly into the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jupyter notebook autocomplete showing duplicate options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48009983/jupyter-notebook-autocomplete-showing-duplicate-options)

Comment: @JDOaktown Im new to Stackoverflow. So I couldn't attach pictures in a normal way (Stackoverflow doesn't allow new sign-up people to upload pictures I guess).